# WebdriverIO how to iterate over elements with same selectors

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io, browser-automation

So for a particular div id, I told webdriverIO to return an array of all the checkboxes inside like this:

`browser.elements('div[data-test-id="filter: inventory source"] input[type="checkbox"]').value;`

This returns:

```
[ { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-8',
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.39366615381480075-8',
    selector: 'div[data-test-id="filter: inventory source"] input[type="checkbox"]',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-8' },
    index: 0 },
  { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-9',
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.39366615381480075-9',
    selector: 'div[data-test-id="filter: inventory source"] input[type="checkbox"]',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-9' },
    index: 1 },
  { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-10',
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.39366615381480075-10',
    selector: 'div[data-test-id="filter: inventory source"] input[type="checkbox"]',
    value: { ELEMENT: '0.39366615381480075-10' },
    index: 2 }]
```

The issue I am running into is the selector(s) are all the same. When I use a forEach loop, I can't iterate to check each checkbox. WebdriverIO will only pick the first one and check that one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Probably when you add `.value` it gets first element value of total elements size.
Not very familiar with WebdriverIO, but try code below:

```
var valueAttrs = 
browser.elements('div[data-test-id="filter: inventory source"] input[type="checkbox"]')
    .map(function(e){ return e.getAttribute('value'); });

valueAttrs.forEach(v=>{console.log('value: ' + v);});
```